# Nuxt 3 wrap useAsyncData to another function

Tags: javascript, fetch, vuejs3, watch, nuxtjs3

I faced with the problem when wrap `useAsyncData` to another function, the **watch** property does not work any more

```js
// functions.ts
export async function testAsync(path: string, watch: (WatchSource<unknown> | object)[]) {   
  return await useAsyncData('filters', () => $fetch(`/api/${path}`, { method: 'GET' }), { watch })
}
```

And call it in another component

```js
const props = defineProps<{modelValue: ToolBarModelValue}>()
let { data: filters } = await testAsync(groupsToApi[props.modelValue.group], [() => props.modelValue.group])
```

When use pure `useAsyncData` in my component, watch property works as expected. Have someone faced with this issue?

Comment: I facing the same problem do you have any solution?